# Cleave.js in React: TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'element')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cleave

I have used Cleave in MANY React projects. But suddenly today it is not working in a new project.

Here are my packages (so you can see versions):

```json
"dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "cleave.js": "^1.6.0",
    "react": "^18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.1.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
```

Here is the implementation of Cleave inside a component:

```js
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
import Cleave from 'cleave.js'

const PhoneInput = ({
  onChange,
  passedValue,
}) => {
  return (
    <Cleave 
      placeholder="Input a phone number" 
      onChange={onChange}
      value={passedValue}
      options={{
        phone: true, 
        phoneRegionCode: 'us'
      }}
    />
  )
}

export default PhoneInput
```

But my compiler keeps throwing the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'element')`

I have tried building this same component in a CodeSandbox to see if it was maybe something with my instance of create-react-app, but I got the same thing in the sandbox as I got here.

I know there are many questions similar to this out there, but each seems specific to the implementation, and no answers that fit my case seemed to exist.

Comment: Can you show the parent component as well?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this. When importing, it is important to use `cleave.js/react` and not just `cleave.js`.

I also needed to import the support files for internationalizing phone numbers, so my imports ended up looking like this:

```js
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
import Cleave from 'cleave.js/react'
import 'cleave.js/dist/addons/cleave-phone.i18n.js'
```